# pandas rolling_std only perform every Nth calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on some code optimization. Currently I use the pandas rolling_mean and rolling_std to compute normalized cross correlations of time series data from seismic instruments. For non-pertinent technical reasons I am only interested in every Nth value of the output of these pandas rolling mean and rolling std calls, so I am looking for away to only compute every Nth value. I may have to write a cython code to do this but I would prefer not to. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
As=5000 #Array size
as=150 #Moving window size
N=3 # only interested in every N values of output array

ar=np.random.rand(As) # generate generic random array
RSTD=pd.rolling_std(ar,as)[as-1:] # dont return the nans before widows overlap


foo=RSTD[::N] # use array indexing to decimate RSTD to only return every Nth value
```

Is there a good pandas way to only calculate every Nth value of RSTD rather than calculate all the values and decimate?

Thanks

Comment: To get this straight, rather than having a running 150-sample window of observation, you want RSTD to calculate only each chunk of 150 samples, correct?

Comment: I think what OP wants is RSTD to calculate STD of each window of size `as` offset by `N`. I.e. `[0:150], [N:150+N], [2*N:150+2*N], ...`

Comment: Thats right, sorry it wasn't clear